# Xcode Travis continuous integration: opt out of testing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, travis-ci

I'm running travis-ci on my iOS project, but I don't use testing. On the contrary Travis uses `xctest` which with my config:

```
language: objective-c

before_install:
    - brew update
    - brew upgrade xctool
    - gem install cocoapods -v '0.33.1'

xcode_workspace: TumblrClient.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: TumblrClient
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator7.0
```

generates this command (with `test`):

```
xctool -workspace TumblrClient.xcworkspace -scheme TumblrClient -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 build test
```

I'd like to completely opt out of testing so that the generated `xctest` command will be like this (without `test`):

```
xctool -workspace TumblrClient.xcworkspace -scheme TumblrClient -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 build
```

How can I accomplish such behavior?